# Can't Increment column value when saving new record in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have created a job in Laravel in order to fetch all location of Devices. When the device boots up a location send, and every time the device has new location a new record insert to DB with the lastest location.

I want to increment the count field whenever a new location been send for the same device. Everything is working find except the COUNT column is not incremented !!

Here is my Job Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Device;
use App\Models\Location;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Notifications\UpdatedMeta;

class SaveDataJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    private $request;
    private $ip;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
      $this->request = $data['request'];
      $this->ip = $data['ip'];
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      $request = $this->request;

      // Try to identify the sender
      $device= $this->identifyDevice($request['meta']);

      // Fetch location data based on IP
      $locationData = $this->getLocationData($this->ip);
      $locationData['ip'] = $this->ip;

      // If we matched the sender, check if a location with the same data exists already. Otherwise create a new location
      if ($device) {
        $locationData['locatable_id'] = $device->id;
        $locationData['locatable_type'] = device::class;
        $location = $this->findLocation($this->ip, $device, $locationData);
      }

// the problem is here, I want to increment the count column when the device has new location
      if (isset($location)){
        $location->count++;
      }
      else {
          $location = Location::create($locationData);
      }

      $location->save();

      // Create and save events
      $this->saveEvents($request['events'], $request['meta'], $device);

      // Update device meta-data
      if ($device) $updated = $device->updateMeta($request['meta']);

      \Log::info("Handled data job");

    }

    private function identifyDevice($meta) {
      $device= null;

      // First try to identify with MAC address
      if (array_has($meta, 'mac')) {
        $device= Device::where('mac_wlan', $meta['mac'])->orWhere('mac_lan', $meta['mac'])->first();
      }

      // If not found, try to identify with device name
      if (!$device&& array_has($meta, 'device_name')) {
        $device= Device::where('device_name', $meta['device_name'])->first();
      }

      return $device;
    }

    private function getLocationData(String $ip) {
      $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
      $result = $client->get('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $this->ip);
      return json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }

    private function findLocation($ip, $device, $locationData) {

        return Location::where('ip', $this->ip)
          ->where('locatable_id', $locationData['locatable_id'])
          ->where('locatable_type', $locationData['locatable_type'])
          ->first();
      }

}
```

Location Table
[image]

Comment: What is your code to count?

Comment: Does `$location->count = $location->count + 1;` work? Echo out the value of `$location->count` before and after the increment. Does it change?

Comment: I want to increment count field in location table when new record inserted
`
if (isset($location)){
        $location->count++;
      }
      else {
          $location = Location::create($locationData);
      }

      $location->save();
` 
@Hanny

Answer (score 0):

Try using `increment()`

```
if ( $location ){
    $location->increment('count');
    $location->save():
}
```

Comment: I tired all these, did not work !!  the reason why it sets to 1 because of inserting new record, I think first I need to return all the records of the same locatable_id, then count(*) device count field then increment it ? right ..